# Escaping wiki markup in the title

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

The wiki markup parser is very confused about the title of [Line-comment in XML — one other than <!— .. -->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327120/line-comment-in-xml-one-other-than).

1. The title ends in `<!`, so the last part gets stripped in some contexts.
2. Some pairs of dashes (which are integral to the meaning of the question) are converted to an mdash, but others aren't. (They also seem to be converted on the fly, as I've seen the page render with two dashes and then switch to long dashes.)

But you can't simply wrap the part in backticks, because unlike wiki markup in the question itself, backtick code escaping doesn't work in the title.

How can I edit the title to be consistent and understandable?

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to reword the title so that the code isn't necessary at all. Perhaps something like: Does XML support a single-line-only comment syntax?

Comment: Maybe, but that doesn't really answer the question. Are you saying that you should never have code in the title of a question?